# Dynamic binding and virtual functions - Vector of base class objects, access the "correct" member function

Tags: c++, oop, virtual-functions

I'm fairly new to c++, and I'm trying to understand as much as possible of the language and the underlying mechanics.

I am confused about a specific case where I can't seem to access the correct member function when I have two classes (Base and Derived) even though I define them as virtual.

```
class Base {
  public:
  virtual void print() { std::cout << "Base" << std::endl; };
};

class Derived : public Base {
  public:
  virtual void print() { std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl; };
};

int main() {

  Base b;
  Derived d;

  b.print();
  d.print();

  Base* p1 = &b;
  Base* p2 = &d;

  p1->print();
  p2->print();

  std::vector<Base> v { b, d };

  v[0].print();
  v[1].print(); // Why doesn't this print "Derived?"

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Base
Derived
Base
Derived
Base
Base <- ??
```

`virtual` seems to "work" with pointers of type `Base`, but not for objects in `vector<Base>`.

**What's going on?**

Comment: You can't create vectors of baseclass objects. This is like assigning a derived object to a base object and causes "slicing" or "truncation". This is a well-known issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of object slicing. When you create your vector you copy your objects into it.

```cpp
std::vector<Base> v{ b, d };
```

The catch is that inside the `std::vector` you have only objects of type `Base`, **NOT** `Base` and `Derived`. If you want polymorphic behavior with containers in C++, you usually do it with pointers, as you can't keep raw references in them.

```cpp
std::vector<Base*> v{ &b, &d };
for (Base* ptr : v) {
    ptr->print();
}
```